# why query between dates returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT regTime FROM customers WHERE 'regTime' BETWEEN '2016-04-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-16 23:59:59'";
```

and the result i get is empty array.

what can be the solution ? and why it's happening ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE 'regTime'
```

If you have to quote column names, use backticks (`).... simple single quotes (`'`) indicate a string literal.... so you're trying to check if the string 'regdate' is between dates, not the column value

Comment: "If you have to quote" , you should include an explanation when he have to use quote them.

Comment: to change it also in the dates ? i changed it everywhere still returns empty

Answer (score 0):

SELECT [originalAlarmTime] FROM [dbo].[Alarms] WHERE originalAlarmTime BETWEEN '2015-07-01 20:18:58.000' AND '2015-07-01 20:20:47.000'

SELECT [originalAlarmTime] FROM [dbo].[Alarms] WHERE originalAlarmTime >= '2015-07-01 20:18:58.000' AND originalAlarmTime <= '2015-07-01 20:20:47.000'